# SELECT query syntax in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.4

I'm self taught in PHP, but i'm afraid my syntax is off for the following MySQL query.

```
$getPassword="SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=$myusername";
$password=mysql_query($getPassword);
```

Is the above registering `$myusername` as a string or as a variable? I'm using PHP 5.4.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it is treating $myusername as a variable, however, when you use php variables in mysql querys you have to do it like so:
$getPassword="SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE username= '".$myusername."'";

Comment: It's best to use PDO.

Comment: take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: I agree with @Be0wulf because PDO has a lot of database support.

Answer (score 5):

Add single quotes to `$myusername` so that it will be read in the query.

```
$getPassword="SELECT `password` FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `username`='$myusername'";
```

Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` because `mysql_*` functions are depracated and will no longer be used in the future.

```
$password=mysqli_query($your_connection, $getPassword);
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to go down this road (and you should), then it's probably wise to look at prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You must put prime symbols around the $myusername variable:

```
$getPassword="SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername'";
$password=mysql_query($getPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $getPassword="SELECT password FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE username='".$myusername."'";
```

Comment: single codes are required for the values in mysql queries , if you want to concat variables with a string. Please look at the below code  $getPassword="SELECT password FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE username='".$myusername."'";

Comment: i have updated my answer please see and if wrong then send me error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php variables which contains strings, you have to enclose it in quotes like,

```
$getPassword="SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername'";
                                                            ^           ^
```

Otherwise, your query will fail to execute.

Answer (score 0):

For the perfect syntax that can make your code much faster...

```
$getPassword="SELECT `password` FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `username`='$myusername'";
```